# What different two recursive directory code?

Tags: c

I saw below code and change only checking file mode, I want to use stat, st_mode. But result is not same. Difference is just checking function.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void listdir(const char *name, int level)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;
    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            path[len] = 0;
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            printf("%*s[%s]\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
            listdir(path, level + 1);
        }
        else
            printf("%*s- %s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
    } while (entry = readdir(dir));
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    listdir(".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

and just change check file_mode

```
void filelist(const char*loc, int dep){

  DIR*dirpt;
  struct dirent* dir;

  if (!(dirpt = opendir(loc)))
      return;

  while((dir = readdir(dirpt))!=NULL)
  {
    struct stat buf;
    lstat(dir->d_name, &buf);

    if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)){

     char p[1024];
     int l = snprintf(p, sizeof(p)-1, "%s/%s", loc, dir->d_name);
     p[l] = 0;
      if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;

      printf("%*s[%s]\n", dep*2,"", dir->d_name);
      filelist(p,dep + 1);
    }
    else 
      printf("%*s- %s\n", dep*2,"", dir->d_name);
  }
  closedir(dirpt);
}
int main(void){
   filelist(".",0);
   return 0;
 }
```

but result is not same, cannot exploring all directory....I don't know why....

Comment: please give us an example of the result you are expecting to see, and an example of the result you are actually getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
lstat(dir->d_name, &buf);
```

In this call, `dir->d_name` does not capture the complete path. It is only the name of the entry in that directory. You should capture the return value of the function and make sure that it was able to get the values you need.

```
if ( lstat(dir->d_name, &buf) == -1 )
{
   // Deal with error
}
```

You'll have to use something like:

```
while((dir = readdir(dirpt))!=NULL)
{
   char p[1024];
   struct stat buf;

   int l = snprintf(p, sizeof(p)-1, "%s/%s", loc, dir->d_name);
   p[l] = 0;

   if ( lstat(dir->d_name, &buf) == -1 )
   {
      // Problem
      continue;
   }

   if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)){

      if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") == 0)
         continue;

      printf("%*s[%s]\n", dep*2,"", dir->d_name);
      filelist(p,dep + 1);
   }
   else 
      printf("%*s- %s\n", dep*2,"", dir->d_name);
}
```